# How to bind a .net dropdown list to a CRM 2011 Option Set

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm sure this is possible, I just haven't got the foggiest how or where to start.

So, I have an option set created in MS Dynamic CRM which gives me a list of countries, MyCountryOptionSet. Lovely.

However, I have a number of other .net, c# applications where users can enter free text. This is not so lovely.

As such, I would like to tie these down so only countries in present in MyCountryOptionSet can be used.

Therefore, I would like to bind the countries from MyCountryOptionSet to a drop down list in my .net applications.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with? Getting the list of options from CRM or binding such data to your control?

Comment: Sorry Greg - getting the list of options from CRM.

Comment: Don't apologise Ricardo - it's just so we can help you easier :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into `RetrieveAttributeRequest` and `IOrganizationService`. This will allow you to get the countries defined in your option set. By casting the `AttributeMetadata` property on the response to `PicklistAttributeMetadata`.

The binding to controls will be UI technology specific so post more info.

Comment: +1 "The binding to controls will be UI technology specific so **post more info**."

Comment: `PicklistAttributeMetadata` contains a Property called `OptionSet` (of type `OptionSetMetadata`) which in turn has a Property called `Options` which inherits from `DataCollection`.  This can all be found in the CRM SDK [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.picklistattributemetadata)

Answer (score 4):

use the crm apis to get option values as follows...

```
_serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serverConfig.OrganizationUri, serverConfig.HomeRealmUri,
                serverConfig.Credentials, serverConfig.DeviceCredentials);
_serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
_service = _serviceProxy;

RetrieveAttributeRequest retrieveAttributeRequest =
    new RetrieveAttributeRequest
    {                            
        EntityLogicalName = EntityLogicalName,
        LogicalName = optionSetLogicalName,
        RetrieveAsIfPublished = true,
    };

// Execute the request.
RetrieveAttributeResponse retrieveAttributeResponse =
    (RetrieveAttributeResponse)_service.Execute(
    retrieveAttributeRequest);

// Access the retrieved attribute.
PicklistAttributeMetadata retrievedPicklistAttributeMetadata =
    (PicklistAttributeMetadata)
    retrieveAttributeResponse.AttributeMetadata;

// Get the current options list for the retrieved attribute.
OptionMetadata[] optionList =
    retrievedPicklistAttributeMetadata.OptionSet.Options.ToArray();

//Dictionary<int,string> LocalizedLabelDic = new Dictionary<int,string>();

List<ListItem> OptionSetItems = new List<ListItem>();

foreach (OptionMetadata o in optionList)
{
    OptionSetItems.Add(new ListItem(o.Label.LocalizedLabels.FirstOrDefault(e => e.LanguageCode == 1033).Label.ToString(), o.Value.Value.ToString()));
}
```

then bind the listitem generic collectoin to ur asp.net drop down

Answer (score 0):

You can query the CRM database directly for the values using a query like this:

```
select Value, AttributeName
from StringMap
where AttributeName = 'New_MySet' --schema name of the global option set
and ObjectTypeCode = 1 --changes based on entity type field is associated with
```

Once you have the results you can bind them to the list in your application.

Comment: ...unless this is a CRM Online deployment (acknowledged that OP didn't tag his question as such,  so it's safe to assume that he is on-premise - but in case anyone is reading this in the future) - in which case SQL is not an option that is avaiable to you.